# Join rows if the same value in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-attribute-value

There is a Postgres database and the table has three columns. The data structure is in external system so I can not modify it.

Every object is represented by three rows (identified by column `element_id` - rows with the same value in this column represents the same object), for example:

```
key     value            element_id
-----------------------------------
status  active           1
name    exampleNameAAA   1
city    exampleCityAAA   1
status  inactive         2
name    exampleNameBBB   2
city    exampleCityBBB   2
status  inactive         3
name    exampleNameCCC   3
city    exampleCityCCC   3
```

I want to get value pair describing every objects. It has to be `name` and `status`.

For this example the output should be like:

```
exampleNameAAA   | active
exampleNameBBB   | inactive
exampleNameCCC   | inactive
```

what is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join

```
select a.value as name,
       b.value as status
from the_table a 
  join the_table b 
    on a.element_id = b.element_id 
   and b."key" = 'status'
where a."key" = 'name';
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/NPJ5782